# Why was Agent Schreck in "Final Destination" so abusive of Alex?

Tags: final-destination

Or was it supposed to not be personal? When the plane explosion happens, Alex is treated as a suspect, although more from Schreck than Weine. Schreck antagonizes him from the get, and when they take him in for questioning, when Ms. Lewton calls the cops on him, he even shoves him into the back seat.
He's the black agent who works with Weine, the white agent.

Weine is the first one to actually let him go based on the fact that he clearly showed to them that he had no control of the deaths, giving away Alex's innocence, yet Schreck clearly seems to want to keep Alex detained against his own will, even when evidence doesn't point to him. Or was this some good cop, bad cop thing? It seemed kinda personal.

Answer (score 3):

If they were around at the time [Agent Block](https://finaldestination.fandom.com/wiki/Jim_Block) (from *Final Destination 5*) was killed, it's possible that Shreck was remembering the last time they had a situation like this, and was afraid to let Alex leave, lest this turn into a repeat of the same situation that killed [Olivia](https://finaldestination.fandom.com/wiki/Olivia_Castle), or worse. He might've considered Alex a teenage version of [Peter Friedkin](https://finaldestination.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Friedkin).

Answer (score -1):

Well clearly he got the suspects reversed with Carter’s temper right now, as Carter loses his temper. and the plane explode, he loses it again, and Todd is killed here.The night of the memorial service, again on the main drag and now Terri. So clearly it was Carter, and the novel makes that doubly clear.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question was about Agent Schreck's treatment of Alex, not if Carter was involved.  From the point of view of the agents, does his treatment of Alex make sense?

Comment: @Carrie Bazzano - If you're the same Carrie Bazzano who posted the [previous answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/252440/122024) to this question, and are unable to access you used to post that answer, you might want to consider merging your new account with the old one, which you can do by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). You'll regain the [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you earned with your previous account, along with the ability to edit your previous answer.